# While editing: HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I can't figure out what problem is... I want to edit some information in modal window... And getting this message.. Input is throug the similar modal, the only difference in name of button and title.
So, the code of my controller is:

```
@Controller
public class GroupController {

    @Autowired
    private GroupService groupService;

    @Autowired
    private ConversationService conversationService;

    @ModelAttribute("group")
    public Group constructGroup() {
        return new Group();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/groups", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doAddGroup(Model model,
            @ModelAttribute("group") @Valid final Group group,
            final BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
            HttpSession httpSession) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(
                    "org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.group",
                    result);
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("group", group);
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("groupNotCreated", true);
            return "redirect:/groups";
        }
        groupService.create(group);
        redirectAttributes.addAttribute("id", group.getId()).addFlashAttribute(
                "groupCreated", true);
        return "redirect:/group?id={id}";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/group/remove/{id}")
    public String removeGroup(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Group group = groupService.findOne(id);
        groupService.delete(group);
        return "redirect:/groups";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/groups", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String groupCreationShow(Model model) {
        Set<Group> groups = groupService.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("groups", groups);
        return "groups";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/group", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showGroups(@RequestParam("id") long id, Model model) {
        Group group = groupService.findOne(id);
        model.addAttribute("group", group);
        addLatestConversationsByGroupId(model, id);
        return "group";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/group-editing", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String groupEditingShow(@RequestParam(value = "id") Long id,
            Model model) {
        Group group = groupService.findOne(id);
        model.addAttribute("group", group);
        return "group-editing";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/group-editing", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String editGroup(@ModelAttribute("group") Group group,
            @RequestParam("id") Long id) {
        group.setId(id);
        groupService.update(group);
        return "redirect:/group?id={id}";
    }

    private void addLatestConversationsByGroupId(Model model, Long id) {
        List<ConversationDto> conversations = conversationService
                .findLatestConversationsDtoByGroupId(id);
        Long conversationsSize = conversationService.countByGroupId(id);
        model.addAttribute("conversationDtos", conversations);
        model.addAttribute("conversationsSize", conversationsSize);
    }
}
```

Servise implementation:

```
@Service
public class GroupServiceImpl implements GroupService {

    @Autowired
    private GroupRepository groupRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Set<Group> findAll() {
        List<Group> list = (List<Group>) groupRepository.findAll();
        Set<Group> items = new HashSet<Group>(list);
        return items;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Group findOne(Long id) {
        return groupRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Group group) {
        groupRepository.delete(group);
    }

    @Override
    public void create(Group group) {
        group.setCreatedAt(new Date());
        groupRepository.save(group);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Group group) {
        groupRepository.saveAndFlush(group);
    }
}
```

Modal form in which I try to edit is:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="group" cssClass="form-horizontal groupForm">
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="groupEditModal" tabindex="-1"
            role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                            aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Group editing...</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="groupName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                Name: </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <form:input path="groupName" cssClass="form-control" />
                                <form:errors path="groupName" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="groupDescription" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                Description: </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <form:input path="groupDescription" cssClass="form-control" />
                                <form:errors path="groupDescription" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success"
                            value="Finish editing!" />
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form:form>
```

I've read a lot about solutions of similar problems, but nothing helps.

Oh, adn there is no errors in Eclipse console.

If you need some more information to understand it better - please ask  me!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which POST URL is giving the error? Please add the JSON & the Java Class for the request.

Comment: where are you getting the error in the jsp page or when you submit the form ??

Comment: Hi! When I submit the form. I found a solution of it. My answer below, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a problem...

Instead of 2 methods in controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/group-editing", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String groupEditingShow(@RequestParam(value = "id") Long id,
            Model model) {
        Group group = groupService.findOne(id);
        model.addAttribute("group", group);
        return "group-editing";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/group-editing", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String editGroup(@ModelAttribute("group") Group group,
            @RequestParam("id") Long id) {
        group.setId(id);
        groupService.update(group);
        return "redirect:/group?id={id}";
    }
```

I wrote only 1 method:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/group", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String editGroup(@ModelAttribute("group") Group group) {
        groupService.update(group);
        return "group";
    }
```

Problem was to easy to understand it at first time (to me!). Edit button is on page of group which i want to edit! So, in that way, I don't need another method to GET this object, I already have it! Because of modal window on the page of group I don't need any @RequestParam... I do changes on the same page with only one object! Modal windows is really cool for such tasks! I hope it can help somebody.